# How to Construct a Lattice from Program Statements

Tags: lattices, data-flow-analysis

In order to optimize a program, I am trying to figure out how the idea of a *lattice* applies to data-flow graphs, as introduced by [this presentation](https://www.google.com/search?q=piazza+dataflow+analysis+and+lattices) (first diagram below). The lattice seems to take a program, order its inputs and outputs, and allow for easily determining flow of variables and state, so you can perform verification and optimization. But I am not sure how to construct the lattice from the program statements.

In this question I would like to know how to construct the lattice from the program.

Specifically, given a program such as this:

```
var x = 10
var y = 20
var z = 0
var i = z
while (i < x) {
  y = y + x * i
  i = i + 1
  z = y + i
}
```

We can construct a Control-Flow Graph (CFG) where each node is a program statement such as `var x = 10`. From that we can construct a Data-Flow Graph (DFG) where we are keeping track of how a variable is used. This creates an [*def-use ordering*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use-define_chain), along the lines of:

```
x, y, i at the same time
z comes after i
...
```

That's where I start getting lost. But once we have a partial ordering, somehow a *lattice* is created. Finally from the lattice, we can do things such as doing *pointer analysis* (Figure 2) and *computing fix-points* (Figure 3). That will help in optimization and verification of the program.

I'm wondering only the first part, **how to construct the lattice from the example program above**. Wondering what is needed to construct the lattice at a high-level. I understand the [upper and lower bounds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551755/understanding-upper-bound-and-lower-bound-in-lattice) of a lattice, which seems to correspond to CFG inputs and outputs being joined, but I don't quite see how to actually do the join (meet), what the nodes/vertices are in the lattice (not sure if it's a single program statement, a variable, or what), and what the edges are in the lattice. Once that is defined, then doing the rest of the stuff should be straightforward. Thank you for your help.

---

[image]

^- Figure (1).

---

[image]

^- Figure (2).

---

[image]

^- Figure (3).

Comment: I think this  is too broad.  You are asking us to explain something that might be an entire chapter of a textbook.  This is not the kind of thing that can be explained in a few paragraphs, so isn't a good fit for our site format -- and when you are having trouble following an explanation in a textbook, that suggests you'll need an especially detailed (and hence) lengthy answer.  I suggest you find a textbook and read about it, and if your first choice is confusing, try to find a different one.  Online references aren't a substitute for a good textbook.

Comment: Good points. Though I would specifically like to know the anatomy of the lattice image in that last picture, how the elements in the program I wrote would show up in a lattice. That's all I want to know.

Comment: The first link is broken.

Comment: @chi Updated, it's a search for "piazza data-flow analysis and lattices", for some reason the links to it though expire after a few hours/days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "DataFlow Graph lattice".  Those are two separate things.  A data flow graph is a graph that represents how data flows in a program, which can be helpful in data flow analysis.  A lattice is a mathematical object that can be helpful for data flow analysis.

Data flow analysis is a broad subject.  There are many techniques for data flow analysis (many use lattices, but it's not a hard requirement).  They don't all use lattices in the same way.  So, there's no one way to do the conversion you are referring to.

To learn more about the subject, I suggest reading a good textbook on program analysis.

Comment: I am not interested in learning about data flow analysis as a broad subject. I am specifically interested in how to construct a lattice from program statements. Updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: @LancePollard, I'm saying that that topic is very broad.  There is not just one way to do that; there are many algorithms for data flow analysis, each of which might construct a different lattice, in a different way.  I still suggest you find a good textbook.